# Getting a list of logical drives

Tags: c#, hard-drive

How can I get the list of logial drives (C#) on a system as well as their capacity and free space?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[`System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives)

Comment: Is this something new that was added in the latest version of .NET. I wrote a small app to display this years ago but had to go the WMI route at the time. Very handy to know anyway... cheers

Comment: Quick look on MSDN: was added in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 38):

```
foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    double freeSpace = drive.TotalFreeSpace;
    double totalSpace = drive.TotalSize;
    double percentFree = (freeSpace / totalSpace) * 100;
    float num = (float)percentFree;

    Console.WriteLine("Drive:{0} With {1} % free", drive.Name, num);
    Console.WriteLine("Space Remaining:{0}", drive.AvailableFreeSpace);
    Console.WriteLine("Percent Free Space:{0}", percentFree);
    Console.WriteLine("Space used:{0}", drive.TotalSize);
    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", drive.DriveType);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

[Directory.GetLogicalDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlogicaldrives.aspx)

Their example has more robust, but here's the crux of it

```
string[] drives = System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives();

foreach (string str in drives) 
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

You could also [P/Invoke](http://www.webtropy.com/articles/art9-1.asp?f=GetLogicalDriveStrings) and call the win32 function (or use it if you're in unmanaged code).

**That only gets a list of the drives however**, for information about each one, you would want to use [GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) as Chris Ballance demonstrates.

Answer (score 7):

maybe this is what you want:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();

foreach (DriveInfo f in DriveInfo.GetDrives())    
    listBox1.Items.Add(f);
```

Comment: You might also want to check the IsReady property

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve this information with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)

```
 using System.Management;

    ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    // Loop through each object (disk) retrieved by WMI
    foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
    {
        // Add the HDD to the list (use the Model field as the item's caption)
        Console.WriteLine(moDisk["Model"].ToString());
    }
```

Theres more info here about the attribute you can poll

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial233_Getting-Disk-Drive-Information-using-WMI-and-Csharp.html

Comment: Can't get this working on my computer. System.Management doesn't have ManagementObjectSearcher class now. The URL is also not pointing to a valid web page.

Comment: You need to add reference for that. On Visual Studio, Right click on project then go to Add -> Reference. Then, search for "System.Management" and add it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wonderful piece of code.

```
ObjectQuery query =
    new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3"); // Create query to select all the hdd's

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
  new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query); // run the query

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get(); // get the results
string sVolumeLabel = "";
string[,] saReturn = new string[queryCollection.Count, 7];
int i = 0; // counter for foreach

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(m["VolumeName"]))) { sVolumeLabel = "Local Disk"; } else { sVolumeLabel = Convert.ToString(m["VolumeName"]); } // Disk Label
  string sSystemName = Convert.ToString(m["SystemName"]); // Name of computer
  string sDriveLetter = Convert.ToString(m["Name"]); // Drive Letter

  decimal dSize = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(m["Size"]) / 1073741824), 2); //HDD Size in Gb
  decimal dFree = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(m["FreeSpace"]) / 1073741824), 2); // Free Space in Gb
  decimal dUsed = dSize - dFree; // Used HDD Space in Gb

  int iPercent = Convert.ToInt32((dFree / dSize) * 100); // Percentage of free space

  saReturn[i,0] = sSystemName;
  saReturn[i,1] = sDriveLetter;
  saReturn[i,2] = sVolumeLabel;
  saReturn[i,3] = Convert.ToString(dSize);
  saReturn[i,4] = Convert.ToString(dUsed);
  saReturn[i,5] = Convert.ToString(dFree);
  saReturn[i,6] = Convert.ToString(iPercent);

  i++; // increase counter. This will add the above details for the next drive.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I deployed an SSIS package and was getting an error simply because on Ballance example we are reading the drives without waiting for them to be ready:

```
string EmailMessage = "";
foreach (var drive in System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (drive.IsReady == true) /*Make sure we can read*/
    {
        double freeSpace = drive.TotalFreeSpace;
        double totalSpace = drive.TotalSize;
        double percentFree = (freeSpace / totalSpace) * 100;
        float num = (float)percentFree;
        //MessageBox.Show("Drive:" + drive.Name + " With " + num + "% free.");
        if (num < 5)
        {
            EmailMessage = "Drive:" + drive.Name + " With " + num + "% free.";
        }
    }
    
}
```