# Cannot run powershell command in c# tests (because of execution policy?)

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio

In a .net8 unit tests, I run a powershell command:

```
protected Collection<PSObject>? GetDisk(int index)
{
    var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    var dir = new Command("Get-Disk");
    dir.Parameters.Add("-Number", index);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(dir);
    pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Get-Partition"));
    pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command("Get-Volume"));

    return pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

And I have set `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` as admin.

Despite this, I still get the following error, and I can't figure out why:

> Message:  Test method DiskManagerTests.DeviceTests.GetDiskTest threw
> exception:  System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The
> 'Get-Disk' command was found in the module 'Storage', but the module
> could not be loaded due to the following error: [File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Storage\StorageScripts.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.] For more information,
> run 'Import-Module Storage'.

> --->
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Storage\StorageScripts.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

> --->
> System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Storage\StorageScripts.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

> --->
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: File
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Storage\StorageScripts.psm1
> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
> For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

> Stack Trace:  AuthorizationManager.ShouldRunInternal(CommandInfo
> commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host)
> ModuleCmdletBase.GetScriptInfoForFile(String fileName, String&
> scriptName, Boolean checkExecutionPolicy)

> (...)

I am running VS2022 as a user (not as administrator).
I am using the package Microsoft.Powershell.SDK 7.4 in the library I am testing.

Comment: Why are you even executing a PowerShell command at all? There's a C# way to list disks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781905/getting-a-list-of-logical-drives

Comment: @gunr2171 those are not equivalent; with the function you mentionned I can't have the relation between the drive index and the rest; and I am starting with the drive index.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the execution policy for this command I had to set it for the process, not the user or the LocalMachine.

> ```
> > get-ExecutionPolicy -list
>
>         Scope ExecutionPolicy
>         ----- ---------------
> MachinePolicy       Undefined
>    UserPolicy       Undefined
>       Process       Undefined
>   CurrentUser    Unrestricted
>  LocalMachine    Unrestricted
> ```

I used this to set the execution policy of the process temporarily:

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
```

and then I could revert to the previous execution policy of the machine and yet run the tests.

> ```
> > get-ExecutionPolicy -list
>
>         Scope ExecutionPolicy
>         ----- ---------------
> MachinePolicy       Undefined
>    UserPolicy       Undefined
>       Process       Undefined
>   CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
>  LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
> ```

Comment: Indeed, setting the process-level execution policy is the right choice for a PowerShell SDK project. The linked duplicate has background information.